# How to deallocate object on c++ which is created on c#

Tags: c#, c++, memory-management, com-interop

I have created a com visible c# dll. I have a factory method to create objects. I can use and create object on c++ but it seems that object are not deallocated. How can I deallocate them. To be clear check the code

-------------------c#------------------------

```
public interface IFoo()
{
    void foo();
}
public class A:IFoo
{
//interface implemented here.
}
public interface IClassFactory
{
     IFoo create();
}
public class TestFactory:IClassFactory
{
 public IFoo create()
 {
     return new A();
 }
}
```

--------------------C++-------------------

```
IClassFactory * ptrClassFactory;
CoInitilize(ptrClassFactory);//
IFoo * mObject = ptrClassFactory->create(); //this object is now garbage colledted //or so ? 
// delete mObject; gives error on my case.
```

Comment: It creates a new A class and returns it as IFoo , look at IClassFactory imp.

Comment: Sorry, read it the other way around; So, how are you releasing the COM objects from your C++ consumer?

Comment: Well this is my problem currently ,I cannot release them. If I call delete * fooPtr , my c++ code crashes. I observed memory usage and see that as long as I create new objects memory that i have used gets bigger.

Comment: @RowlandShaw yes I mean mObject->Release();

Answer (score 1):

Don't **ever** call `delete` on a pointer to a COM object, as the object is reference counted, you should call `Release()` on the COM instances to release the reference count - the object can then free its memory/resources as it sees fit

Comment: I wrote a test method and tried to see if its really works. In a for loop I called IFoo * mObject = ptrClassFactory->create(); IFoo->Release(). But its crashes on release method after some points. For my case it crashes when i == 300.

Comment: There's no `i` in your code, so I can only refer you to your debugger, which might be able to provide more detail of *why* it's failing (exception, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your are talking about COM.
Since the object is supposed to inherit from IUnknown then you have the AddRef Release methods which are used for exactly that purpose of releasing the memory of the object when it is no longer needed by using a ref count on the object.

Simply call release and implement release in C# to do nothing if it isn't already implemented that way.

If you are not talking about COM then you can still use the COM way of releasing objects.
Keep a ref count in C# and add C# functions that C++ will call to update the object.
When the ref count reaches zero then C++ no longer needs the object and it can be discarded and left for the garbage collector.